# Certificate pinning and downloadmanager

Tags: android, security, ssl, certificate-pinning

I am trying to use Certificate Pinning. I have my application downloading files using `DownloadManager`. I was wondering if I use `DownloadManager` will that support the certificate that I have pinned in android manifest and `network_security_config.xml`. If not what download method would use the certificate pinning

this is my network-security-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=</pin>
            <!-- backup pin -->
            <pin digest="SHA-256">fwza0LRMXouZHRC8Ei+4PyuldPDcf3UKgO/04cDM1oE=</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

These digests aren't real.

Comment: AFAIK, no, as the actual downloading work requested via `DownloadManager` is being done by another process.

Comment: @CommonWare What download method would allow me to use certificate pinning. Also could you provide some code examples.

Comment: "What download method would allow me to use certificate pinning" -- anything that is in your own process. I use OkHttp. "Also could you provide some code examples" -- code examples of what?

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please provide code examples of pinning certificates using Okhttp.

Comment: There is nothing specific to OkHttp about using network security configuration. There is nothing in Java that you have to do to enable network security configuration on Android 7.0+. If you want to use [my backport of network security configuration](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity), *then* there is some Java configuration, and I cover that in the documentation. In terms of using OkHttp in general, they have [quite a bit of documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes).

Comment: How to generate the SHA-256 of my SSL Certificate?